# Consistently getting text from XML nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, child-nodes

I know this has been asked a lot, but I've followed the advice and I'm still getting some very specific, seemingly inconsistent behaviour from my xml/jQuery files:
Before I get to the question, here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $body = $('body');
    var currentXMLObjects;
    var $currentXMLContainers = new Array();
    var previousXMLObjects;
    $body.append("<div id='content'><h3>Staff Organisational Chart</h1></div>");
    // Load the xml file using ajax 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/content.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $xml = $(xml);
            console.log(xml.children[0]);
            appendNewContainers(xml.children[0].children);
        }
    });

    function appendNewContainers(children) {
        currentXMLObjects = children;
        console.log("currentXMLObjects.length = "+currentXMLObjects.length);
        for (var x=0;x<currentXMLObjects.length;x++) {
            $currentXMLContainers.push( $( currentXMLObjects[x] ) );
            $("#content").append('<div class="container"><div>' + currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue + '</div><div>' + currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue + '</div><div>' + currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue + '</div></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

And here's the XML:

```
<content>
    <level name="first name">
        <title>Title 1 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 1</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 1</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact> 
    </level>
    <level name="second name">
        <title>Title 2 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 2</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 2</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
    <level name="third name">
        <title>Title 3 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 3</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 3</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
    <level name="fourth name">
        <title>Title 4 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 4</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 4</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
    <level name="fifth name">
        <title>Title 5 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 5</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 5</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
</content>
```

Now what I'm TRYING to do is get the text from the title, firstName and lastName nodes and append them in divs to a containing div.

It took me a while, experimenting with various arrangements of .childNodes[0], firstChild and nodeValue, to realise that I could get the text of each 'title' using the the index '1' in currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[1]... Problem is I can't seem to access the firstName and lastName nodes. I have tried all the arrangements I can think of:

currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].nodeValue throws a null error, as does:
currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue

currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[1].nodeValue returns and appends 'null', and

currentXMLObjects[x].childNodes[2].nodeValue appends nothing.

Similarly any combination missing the middle 'childNodes[n]' returns either null or nothing at all.

Anyone have any clues as to what's happening here? I'm surprised the 'title' node is seemingly so deeply nested in the XML; the nodeList being sent to the 'appendNewContainers' function is already being drilled down into. But looking for the child nodes of a 'level' element doesn't work at a shallower depth.

Any help, much appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use jQuery also for the xml data? Check out this example (using your current xml structure): [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/f2gzo3uo/)

```
var $target = $('content');
$target.children().each(function(){
    $body.append($(this).attr('name') + "<br />");
    $body.append($('title', this).text() + "<br />");
    $body.append($('lastName', this).text() + "<br />");
    $body.append($('contact', this).text() + "<br />");
    $body.append('<br /><br/>');
});
```

**Edit:**

Using your code structure (including an example with jQuery): [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/f2gzo3uo/1/)

```
var xml = $('content');

appendNewContainers(xml[0].children);

function appendNewContainers(children) {
    currentXMLObjects = children;

    for (var x= 0; x < currentXMLObjects.length; x++) {
        $("#content").append(
            '<div class="container"><div>' + currentXMLObjects[x].children[0].innerText + 
            '</div><div>' + currentXMLObjects[x].children[1].innerText + 
            '</div><div>' + currentXMLObjects[x].children[2].innerText + '</div></div>'
        );
    }

    $('#content').append('<br style="margin-bottom: 40px" />');

    // jQuery way using tag names
    $(currentXMLObjects).each(function(){
        $("#content").append(
            '<div class="container"><div>' + $('title', this).text() + 
            '</div><div>' + $('firstName', this).text() + 
            '</div><div>' + $('lastName', this).text() + '</div></div>'
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - maybe I should have said; I'm using an external xml file so that an admin (or someone with less coding experience) will be able to update the web app. I'd really like to know what's happening with the simple set up I've got.

Comment: Once loaded, an external file becomes an xml structure like the example that I posted. I think you are complicating things. Your current code doesn't work because you are trying to access nodes that don't exist. I updated my answer with your code arranged.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. Although I can't seem to make this work with an external xml file. I also don't understand why I can access the 'title' nodes and NOT the others. Why don't those nodes exist?

Comment: Make a console.log (or better use a break point) and check by yourself the existent properties of the objects. I've worked a lot with xml structures to fill html and maps and the easiest way (using jQuery) is using the tag names. Check out and try with the code inside this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/o1my8bm0/. I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: I have been console.log-ing the heck out of this, but it hasn't made it any clearer. When I get a text object returned, I can't then extract any text. Some objects will have a length but I can't access them with square brackets. Also the problem with using the tag names is that I want to get tags of specific depths only - as the user traverses up and down the staff hierarchy. I think I'm going to switch to having one type of tag ('level') and using attributes (eg name="name here") to describe each element.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be an idea to append the retrieved xml to the document, and query the content using querySelectors? Something like (simple no jQuery example, but should be easy to use jQuery for appending the xml and querying it):

```js
var xml = document.querySelector('content');

var names = document.querySelectorAll('[name]');
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

[].slice.call(names).forEach(
  function(nameElement) {
    result.textContent += 
      nameElement.querySelector('firstName').textContent + ' ' +
      nameElement.querySelector('lastName').textContent +
      '\n';
  } 
);
```

```css
content {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>

<content>
    <level name="first name">
        <title>Title 1 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 1</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 1</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact> 
    </level>
    <level name="second name">
        <title>Title 2 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 2</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 2</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
    <level name="third name">
        <title>Title 3 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 3</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 3</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
    <level name="fourth name">
        <title>Title 4 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 4</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 4</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
    <level name="fifth name">
        <title>Title 5 Here</title>
        <firstName>First Name 5</firstName>
        <lastName>Last Name 5</lastName>
        <contact>Active</contact>
    </level>
</content>
```

Comment: I'm going to have 'level' elements nested within 'level' elements so I don't think this approach will work; I'm trying to pass just the 'current' depth of 'level' elements to the appendNewContainers function (The eventual web-app will represent a staff hierarchy). So I can't collect the elements by the 'name' attribute as 'level' elements at all depths will have that attribute.

Comment: If you have control over the XML it should be possible to add unique (data-) attributes to it to identify specific (ranges of) elements. Maybe using json is a viable alternative too.

Comment: The xml needs to be as simple as possible so admin folk can maintain the web app (no offence to admin folk). Any idea why I can access the 'title' node but not the 'firstName' or 'lastName' nodes?